# How long should unattended-upgrades take?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, unattended-upgrades

I have ran `sudo unattended-upgrades` while SSH'd into a Ubuntu box forgetting the  `-d` or `-v` flag, so it is almost entirely silent. My Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS said that it had 175 security updates(!) and my line speed is about 2-3Mbps.

How long should that take?

It's been running for around 25 minutes which seems like a long time to me (On an SSD), is this OK? Can I close my SSH client and let it run?